# Trying to setup virtual hosts on unix PHP on nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, unix, php-fpm

I have tried to install php5-fpm and Nginx on Ubuntu machine, but I got a problem. When I have only one virtual host on a unix port it is all fine but when I try to add another virtual host Nginx goes to default web page "Welcome to Nginx!" but when I run it on a tcp port example port 9000 it work fine with multisites. It is a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10, Nginx 1.2.3 with php5-fpm installed. It also has extra php installs such as php-apc. I can only give the links to the virtual hosts because I am doing it from a mobile phone. Here are the links for the two virtual hosts I am using: http://ic0nic.co.uk/ic0nic.txt, http://ic0nic.co.uk/sourproxy.txt also I want to use unix port because I find it a whole lot faster.

Edit: Here are the nginx configs

```
    server {
    server_name ic0nic.co.uk www.ic0nic.co.uk;
    root /var/www/ic0nic.co.uk;
    listen 8080;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    include conf.d/drop;

        location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
        root /var/www/ic0nic.co.uk;

        }
}

server {
    server_name sourproxy.co.uk www.sourproxy.co.uk;
    root /var/www/sourproxy.co.uk/;
    listen 8080;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    include conf.d/drop;

        location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/sourproxy.co.uk$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems confused to me. Please change your configuration like the following and tell me if this solves the problem. If not please post your nginx error log.

```
# /etc/sites-available/server.conf

listen 8080;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
include conf.d/drop;
location / {
  location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Your actual virtual host configuration for `ic0nic.co.uk`:

```
# /etc/sites-available/ic0nic.co.uk.conf

server {
  server_name ic0nic.co.uk www.ic0nic.co.uk;
  root /var/www/ic0nic.co.uk;
  include sites-available/server.conf;
}
```

Your actual virtual host configuration for `sourproxy.co.uk`:

```
# /etc/sites-available/sourproxy.co.uk.conf

server {
  server_name sourproxy.co.uk www.sourproxy.co.uk;
  root /var/www/sourproxy.co.uk;
  include sites-available/server.conf;
}
```

Please note that this configuration is far from being ideal. For instance the `index` directive should go directly into your `nginx.conf` within the `http` context.

Have you verified your php-fpm configuration to use sockets instead of listening on a TCP port? Check the pool configurations and if everything is fine in there enter `netstat -an`, you should see the php-fpm sockets listed there.

Always check the error log. You can simply `cat /dev/null > /var/log/nginx/error.log` to purge the log file. Start nginx and php-fpm and try to open your website. Post the result of the log file here!